# Prevent autologin to the admin account

Tags: ubuntu, users, login

I am a new user of Linux. I have both window 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.
For my family and friends, I make Guest account but when I restart my laptop and operates with Windows 7 then options are comes for admin and guest.
when I start my Linux operating system then it automatically starts with admin account without asking password.
What to do?

Comment: are you using Ubuntu/Unity, Ubuntu/GNOME, Ubuntu/XFCE (Xubuntu)?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on your login manager. It's probably configured for automatic login. Just remember that, to actually change something significant, you'd have to type your password(sudo). Check the config files.

Alternatively, you could set a password at boot-time(obviously through the bios could work as well) which would require a password after grub.
Or LUKS encryption.

Comment: This answer isn't really helpful without explaining where to switch automatic login off.

Answer (score 0):

go to Menu -> Administration -> Login Window Preferences -> Automatic Login

Then uncheck any user that is set to auto login.